# why is an assembly config overwriting the app.config?

Tags: c#-4.0, app-config

I have an old assembly, lets call it commonCode.dll.    Up till now it did not contain an app.config.  I moved some settings to this app.config for this assembly.  The settings for the app.config are:

Copy to Output Directory:  Copy Always.

Now here is the thing when I build my code it appears that this contents of this file are being overwritten in app.config.  Meaning the app.config of the executable now contains the contents of this file.  I am at a loss of what could be happening.